# PenTest warnings for JavaScript libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, testing

We've done a PenTest on our new .NET web application and have got warnings for the JavaScript files included in the html pages. All of them are third party libraries like:

knockout-3.0.0.js, jquery.validate.js, jquery-ui-1.0.2.js, jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js, jquery.js, jquery.unobtrusive.js, jquery.validate.js.....

Is there any way to fix these issues?

**Examples:**

**Anti CSRF tokens scanner**

**Risk**: High

**Reliability**: Warning

**URLs**: 1-https://www.ourwebaddress.com/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.min.js
**Parameters**: None. Warning only.

**Attack**: No known Anti-CSRF tokens were found in the following HTML 
........................................................................

**X-Content-Type-Options header missing**

**Risk:** Low

**Reliability:** Warning

**URLs:** 
1-https://www.ourwebaddress.com/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.min.js 
........................................................................

**Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled**

**Risk:** High

**Reliability:** Warning

**URLs:** 1-https://www.ourwebaddress.com/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.min.js

The X-XSS-Protection HTTP response header allows the web server to enable or disable the web browser's XSS protection mechanism.

The following values would attempt to enable it:

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

X-XSS-Protection: 1; report=http://www.example.com/xss

The following values would disable it:

X-XSS-Protection: 0 
The X-XSS-Protection HTTP response header is currently supported on Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari (WebKit).